# Visual Studio 2010 - EmbeddedResource Assembly set wrong .Net framework Version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, embedded-resource, .net-assembly

I have a solution containing several projects (some in .Net 4.0 and some in 3.5 and 2.0)

Among those projects I have one project containing embedded resources only, this project is set to target framework 2.0 and does not explicitly references any other assembly

When compiled with vs2010 it creates an assembly referencing mscorlib 4.0 and so cannot be loaded by project below .NET 4.0

I have no control on the `mscorlib` reference so how can I really compile the project in .NET 2.0 version so it can be loaded by all others project in the solution??

Thanks in advance ;)